# Where is the whitespace in Fparsec v. 0.9.2 (newbie)?

Tags: f#, fparsec

In Fparsec V.0.8, there is `FParser.CharParser.whitespace`. But in Fparsec 0.9.2, there isn't `FParser.CharParser.whitespace`.Where is the whitespace in Fparsec v. 0.9.2?

When I tried to compile the project "Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours in F#" (visit http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Write-Yourself-a-Scheme-in-d50ae449), the problem was met.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `FParser.CharParser.spaces`.

The code you linked fails in this line:

```
let spaces1 : LispParser<unit> = skipMany1 whitespace
```

But there is also `spaces1` already defined, so you can just delete that line and it will compile.

Have a look at http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/charparsers.html#members.spaces